# SQL method to return if all in join match conditions

Tags: sql, mariadb

I've been browsing this site for quite a while and this is my first post so I hope I've learned the correct way how to inquire... I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while even with all the available information I'm still lost.

I have 3 tables.
Sets, UserBudget, ItemCosts

```
table name               column names
-----------              ------------------------
Sets                     SetID 
UserBudget               UserID | ItemID | ItemBudget 
ItemCosts                SetID  | ItemID | ItemPrice
```

ItemCosts contains multiple items, that are connected to a 'Sets' table entry.

I need a way to return the SetID's from the first table only if the UserBudget has all the same items as ItemCosts and all the ItemPrice is equal or lower to ItemBudget.

For example:

```
Sets                ItemCosts                 UserBudget
-----------         ----------                ----------
SetID      1        SetID      1              UserID     1
                    ItemID     1    2         ItemID     1    2 
                    ItemPrice  10   12        ItemBudget 11    11
```

This is not supposed to return anything since the second item's price is higher than the user's budget for it.

```
Sets                ItemCosts                 UserBudget
-----------         ----------                ----------
SetID      1        SetID      1              UserID     1
                    ItemID     1    2         ItemID     1    2 
                    ItemPrice  10   12        ItemBudget 11    12
```

This is supposed to return Set 1.

Any of my attempts just end up returning the set if one of the items matches the budget.
Here's my current SQL (it's a super simplified version in the end as all my complicated attempts took longer to execute but returned the same result):

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserBudget a 
  INNER JOIN ItemCosts b on a.ItemID=b.ItemID 
  INNER JOIN Sets c on b.SetID=c.SetID 
WHERE a.UserID=1 AND a.ItemBudget>=b.ItemPrice
```

Comment: Please provide sample data as SQL INSERT statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next solution:

```
SELECT a.UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.SetID) SetIDs
FROM UserBudget a 
LEFT JOIN ItemCosts b on a.ItemID=b.ItemID  AND a.ItemBudget>=b.ItemPrice
LEFT JOIN Sets c on b.SetID=c.SetID 
WHERE a.UserID=1
GROUP BY a.UserID
HAVING COUNT(a.UserID) = COUNT(b.SetID)
;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c284e61b2a07ea73d6357e1b6214d85c&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)